# Need to calculate my final marks - help

Tags: calculator

I don't know the formula to calculate my marks for a subject. The first tests accounts for 38% of the overall grade whereas the final exam accounts for 62%. Let us say that on the first test I got a mark of 80% and the second one 60%. What is my final grade and how do I calculate that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is some ambiguity. Was there one test (your mark $80$) and one final exam (your mark $60$)? If so, answer in principle is simple, $(80)(0.38)+(60)(0.62)$. Except that often marks are manipulated at the end. Ordinarily upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was one test (during the course) on which you earned $80\%$,  and a final exam on which you earned $60\%$, then you simply multiply scores earned by their respective weights/proportions, $$(80\times 0.38)+(60\times 0.62) = 67.6\%\quad\text{grade for course}$$

---

If you earned the grades of $80$ and $60$ on two tests *during the course* and need to determine what grade you'll need on the final to pass the class, then let's say you need to earn a $70\%$ in the course, overall, to pass. Let $P =$ needed grade on the final. Then you need to solve for $P$ given:

$$\frac{(80 + 60)}{2}\times 0.38 +  0.62 P = 70$$

As it happens, in this scenario, you will have earned an average grade of $70$ on the tests, and will therefore need to earn at least $70\%$ on the final, as well, to earn a course grade of at least $70\%$

Comment: nice write up again +1

Answer (score 1):

For a given set of percentage weights for items and your overall score for each item, you can just sum the products of the weights and scores.

In this case, you have $total = w_i*x_i + w_j*x_j = 0.38*0.80 + 0.62*0.60 = 0.676$ So you've earned a 67.6%.